# how to read from a json file and create a environment variable in cli?

Tags: json, linux, macos, amazon-web-services

I want to read the aws credentials file and create the aws keys environment variable dynamically by reading the file

I need this because I have aws credentials expiring on short terms

so every time i need to created a new set of keys and then set it to env variables

what I want is to parse the credential file and set it directly to env variable

I have the credentials in a json file

I am using 'jq' to parse the json by command

`cat credentials.json | jq .Credentials.AccesskeyId`

`cat credentials.json | jq .Credentials.SecretKey`

now how can I use the output in setting the value in something like

`export AWS_ACCESS_KEY = output of (cat credentials.json | jq .Credentials.AccesskeyId)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for what you want to achieve is the following:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(cat credentials.json | jq .Credentials.AccesskeyId)
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(cat credentials.json | jq .Credentials.SecretKey)
```

I tested this in both `bash` and `zsh` shells.

Comment: Consider using `$()` https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006

Comment: echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID , returns null

Comment: typo mistake for me , works for me now , please edit the answer a bit so i can upvote it , currently I cant

Comment: If the quotation marks are still in the ENV variable, you can pipe the following at the end sed 's/"//g'. So 

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(cat credentials.json | jq .Credentials.AccesskeyId | sed 's/"//g')